# Quorum Maker for recovery of blockchain data in secondary node

Tags: quorum

We are trying to setup multiple nodes in QUorum maker to make one node as a backup to be used in case the primary node fails for some reason. We are able to deploy our smart contract successfully but we find that the node directory gets populated with the contract address in the first node only but not in the second node.

Can quorum maker be used to have two nodes configured in "fault-tolerance" mode in such a way that if one node goes down, the front end application can still recover the blockchain data from the second node configured in quorum maker?

If so, kindly let us know the procedure for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Quorum Maker is not a tool to set up your production and fault tolerance nodes with Quorum. Its a bit out of date now and forces you to use older version of client. My recommendation would be to connect with our core engineers on our slack and ask for some sample configurations for resilience. Both Tessera and Quorum client offer several layers for DR and availability

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Kindly let know which is the most active slack forum and a link to it.

Comment: Apologies for forgetting to provide a link, here you go: http://bit.ly/quorum-slack